# Return focus to the last position in editing in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a Vim command which could returns the focus to the position be just edited? This is very useful after some code searching for edit.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do `g;`, jump back to the last changed position.

Note that, `g;` will go to the last position in **change list**, that is, no matter your change was done in insert or normal mode, once it was in your change list, `g;` is gonna bring you there.

You can keep pressing `g;` to navigate your change list.

`g,` is for opposite direction.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>gi</kbd> - Insert text in the same position as where Insert mode was stopped last time in the current buffer.

<kbd>`^</kbd> or <kbd>'^</kbd> - Jump to the position where the cursor was the last time when Insert mode was stopped.

<kbd>`.</kbd> or <kbd>'.</kbd> - Jump to the position where the last change was made.

Comment: Is there any difference between `\`^` and `'^`?

Comment: one is line#, one is line+col (position) @Ben